# How to call a method on a model after a form selection is made

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update a model after a selection is made on a selection menu.

If the selection is 'se' for example, I want to call a method that updates the current users profile.

Heres my view:

```
<h1>Profiles#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/profiles/new.html.erb</p>

<%= simple_form_for @profile do |f| %>
<%= f.input :bio %>

<%= select_tag id="postcode"name="Areas Covered">
    <option value="se">Southeast London</option>
    <option value="nw">  </option>
    <option value="n">  </option>
    <option value="s">  </option>
  </select>
 <br><br>

<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

If 'se' is called I'll call the "se_london" helper method:

```
module ProfilesHelper

    def se_london
        se = Place.where('area2 LIKE ? AND postal_code LIKE ?', '%London%', '%se%')
        @profile.places << se
    end
end
```

I'm trying to call the method on the current user profile but to no avail:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new

  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    if @profile.save
      if "value" == se
        @profile.se_london
      end
      redirect_to '/' 
    else
      redirect_to '/'
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
    @profile = Profile.all
  end

  def show
  end
```

If its relevant, the Place model has a belongs to and has many relationship with the Profile model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to read up on how to use `select_tag` [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag). You could do something like this:

```
<%= label_tag :areas_covered, "Areas Covered" %>
<%= select_tag :areas_covered, options_for_select(['se', 'nw', 'n', 's']) %>
```

This will place the selection in the `params` hash as `params[:areas_covered]`. Then, from the controller, you could do:

```
@profile.se_london if params[:areas_covered] == 'se'
```

As it stands right now, in your controller,  you are testing to see if the string "value" is equal to a variable, or the return value of a method, named `se`, which is not even defined as far as I can see. That test will never pass, and will even throw an error.